# How do I assign a list retrieved by Dapper to the properties in my class model?

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a model class that has a number of public properties (name, address, etc.).  These properties exactly match the columns in a SQL database.  I have a form that permits a user to put in a Client ID number, and on click, passes the Client ID to a method in a business logic class that in turn calls a general data access class that uses a Dapper Query to return the client record from the SQL database.  This result is bound to a datagridview, and it works fine.

(So this works fine:  Form > BLClass > DataAccessClass > BLClass > Form)

However, in my business logic class, I would like to have access to all of the properties in my model class, so I can generate reports and run some calculations.  I can create a new, empty instance of my model class and all of the properties appear after the dot in intellisense, but when I try to access the actual list returned by the DataAccess Class, which is of type List, I can't set or get any of the properties in the model class.

Note: My business class method started as a public void method, but in order to return the list to the form for use in the datagridview I had to make the method "public List CreateReport(int ClientID);"  I don't care about displaying the result on the form - I can always populate that separately.  I just need to be able to populate the properties of the model class inside the business logic class so I can use them in a report.

```
//The model class
public class ClientModel
{

    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientPosition { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string MName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    //etc.  
}

//The business logic class 

public void CreateReport(int ClientID);

List<ClientModel> client = DataConfig.Connection.GetClientByID(ClientID).ToList();

string ClientName = (client.FName + " " + client.MName + " " + client.LName).ToUpper();
string ClientNameFooter = client.FName + " " + client.MName + " " + client.LName;

//Etc., with the int's and strings eventually replacing bookmarked sections in a Word template using Word.Interop.
```

When I try to access client.Fname, I get the error "List' does not contain a definition for 'FName' and no accessible extension method 'FName' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found."

I tried assigning the list variable "client" to an empty instance of the Client model, but I got the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ReportGenerator.ClientModel' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List.ReportGenerator.ClientModel'.

New to C# and Dapper, so this could be something completely obvious I'm missing with the list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `client` is a list. The is no Fname on the list. You can do

```
client[0].Fname
```

or index it in another way.

Since you are new, here are some other hints:

- Do yourself and those who need to maintain the code after you a favour and use long variable/property names. So FirstName instead of Fname.
- Be consistent. Don't call one property Fname and another MName.
- By convention local variables start with small letters: clientName not ClientName.
- Use string interpolation:

  ```
  string clientName = "{client.FName} {client.MName} {client.LName}".ToUpper();
  ```

**EDIT**:
Looking at your question again I think you want to use `FirstOrDefault` or `Single`. `FirstOrDefault` will take the first item in your list or default (null) if the list is empty. `Single` will take exactly one item if there is one and otherwise throw an exception.

```
ClientModel client = DataConfig.Connection.GetClientByID(ClientID).Single();
```

Then you will not have to iterate or index into the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried changing the Query type to Single/SingleOrDefault/First/FirstOrDefault ... they all compiled fine, but threw the same "System.ArgumentNullException."  I started to debug it, but honestly, it will work fine for me to just use the index of the client list to generate the report.  I guess I thought that Dapper would be able to somehow map that list to a model, but because they are two different types of objects, it makes sense that I would have to enumerate the list somehow.

Comment: Also:  Thanks for the comments about the code.  I will gladly take all of the hints I can get.  It's actually much worse than you think.  This is all roughly based on some mid-90's Access VBA that is ... interesting.  I'm trying to clean it up, bring it into the 90's, and learn C# at the same time.  It's actually a great language for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Dapper as described in the tutorial here: https://dapper-tutorial.net/query

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ClientModels";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{           
    var clientModels = connection.Query<ClientModel>(sql).ToList();
    foreach(var clientModel in clientModels)
    {
        // do something with clientModel
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're passing in a ClientId... sounds unique.. therefore, maybe it's not a list that you need..

```
public void CreateReport(int ClientID)
{
    try
    {
         ClientModel client = DataConfig.Connection.GetClientByID(ClientID).FirstOrDefault();

         if(client != null)
         {
             string ClientName = (client.FName + " " + client.MName + " " + client.LName).ToUpper();
             string ClientNameFooter = client.FName + " " + client.MName + " " + client.LName;

             Debug.WriteLine("ClientName: {0}", ClientName);
             Debug.WriteLine("ClientNameFooter: {0}", ClientNameFooter);
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.WriteLine("Couldn't find a client with that Id...");
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```